# Change log path in Monolog - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

Currently I've this configuration in config.yml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        applog:
            type: stream
            path: /var/log/my_file.log
            level: error
```

And in my controller, I use:

```
$logger = $this->get('logger');
$logger->info("test");
```

But, always this information "test" is writed in /var/log/prod.log

How can I change this to my_file.log?

Thanks

Comment: I am really interested in why this doesn't work. After all it really resembles the example from official docs :-/

Comment: Yes, I'dont know what is the problem, but I need to change this and the logs continuos writting in prod.log

Answer (score 2):

Add `channel`to your handler config:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        applog:
            type: stream
            path: /var/log/my_file.log
            level: error
            channel: my_channel
```

Now you can get logger service for that channel:

```
$logger = $this->get('monolog.logger.my_channel');
```

Furthermore, have in mind that your logging level is `error` for **applog** handler so `$logger->info` will not be visible in file specified. However, `$logger->error` will be.